# Are JavaScript events working if i am using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, dom-events

I am new at creating applications using jQuery but I am quite familiar with Javascript. Well, what I am trying to do is use the Javascript getElementById in order to draw an image in html5 canvas. My code is:

Include the jQuery and JQuery mobile:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="lib/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery-1.6.1.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>
```

The code with problem:

```
     <div data-role="content">
      <!--//TO DO canvas drawing-->
      <canvas id="draw_area" width="295px" height = "390px"></canvas>
      ...

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var canvas = getElementById("draw_area");
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var map = new Image();

      map.src = "./imgs/home_screen1.png";
      map.onload = function (){
          context.drawImage (map, 0, 0);
      };
 </script>
```

I also noticed that I am not able to use the

```
<body onload = "aFunction();">
```

not any other Javascript event like "onclick".

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: what is `aFunction()` ? What browser are you using?

Comment: So what, **exactly**, is "the problem"? I.e. what do you expect to happen, and what actually happens? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @RobG: The problem is that there is invalid script preventing execution of subsequent scripts.  The error should be _Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined_ in the console.

Comment: An error in that script will not necessarily stop other scripts from running in other script elements or the body's onload handler from running. Perhaps the OP's load function was dependent on the result of the failed code, who knows?

Comment: @RobG: Sorry Rob, you're right.  the `getElementById` problem will prevent the rest of the script _in that block_ from running, but wouldn't in itself explain why `aFunction()` isn't called on load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("draw_area");
```

Your script is running the `getElementById` line as soon as it is loaded, which is failing (due to the missing `document.`) and preventing the scripts on the rest of your page from executing.

[Here's a quick demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/AWELc/) to show you how script errors will prevent subsequent lines from executing.

Once that's fixed, as @swalk says, you should encapsulate that script so it runs on [`document.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to keep things tidy.

Comment: @RobG: `getElementById()` is a function on the `document` object, using it without `document.` won't work and will prevent execution of subsequent scripts. If the OP checks their error console they'll be seeing something along the lines of _Uncaught ReferenceError: getElementById is not defined_.  +1? ;)

Comment: This will cause your javascript to start working again. Also, technically the OP doesn't need to wrap their code in a `document.ready` call, as the element that it's working on has been loaded. But it is the *right* thing to do :)

Comment: @Blair McMillan: You're right, 'need' was too strong a word. I've updated that bit of my answer.

Comment: @Town — I read "missing document" as meaning that the DOM wasn't available, not that the identifier *document* was missing. Score adjuseted.

Comment: @Town: Thank you very much, that was indeed my problem. I was not aware that I need to use the `document.`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect it's because you aren't using jQuery's dom ready function. Any JavaScript that manipulates/accesses the DOM should be done after DOM ready. Even if this isn't the issue, this is a common problem when people are new to JavaScript or jQuery.

Most jQuery code is usually found within this ready function: http://api.jquery.com/ready/.

For example, your code should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  var canvas = getElementById("draw_area");
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var map = new Image();

  map.src = "./imgs/home_screen1.png";
  map.onload = function (){
    context.drawImage (map, 0, 0);
  };
});
</script>
```

Comment: `ready()` or not, `var canvas = getElementById("draw_area");` won't work (unless the OP has defined their own implementation of `getElementById`, for some reason!).

Comment: The problem with the  `<body onload= afunction();` still exists. @James, @RobG I am working on phonegap, creating an app for iphone. `afunction()` could be any function in a different js file triggering an alert. How could I use the `document.ready` in a js file? Sorry for the question if it sounds silly...